# google - SEO guides

Tags: seo, openshift

I have deployed the following application to OpenShift and I think I'm doing something wrong with the seo steps I followed.

https://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com

Whenever I search about `actibities` in google my site appears at the 3rd page but instead of showing the home page, it shows a "sub" page `pages/actibities-history`. I have tried to submit my content through webmaster tools but with no luck.

Any ideas about how I should re-crawl in order to adopt the appropriate site structure?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did You upload sitemap to google ? Thats best way to organize Your page structure.

Comment: I did but seems like it ignores it...